# Infimum and continuity

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ and for every x in [a,b], there is a y in [a,b] such that
$ |f(y)| < \frac{1}{2} |f(x)| $. What is the minimum value of $|f(x)|$. Also show that f is not continuous on [a,b].

Comment: This looks like a interesting problem what have you tried so far and what difficulties have you run into?

Comment: Also does the question say "minimum value" or "infimum"?

Comment: Start of with any x in [a,b]. By the given condition we can find a y1 such that |f(y1)| < 1/2 |f(x)|. Then again using the given condition we we get y2 such that |f(y2)| < 1/2|f(y1)| < 1/2^2 |f(x)|.  We get a sequence yn such that |f(yn)|< 1/2^n |f(x)|, which shows that lim |f(yn)| =0 provided |f(x)| is finite. I feel that the infimum should be 0 but cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1):

$|f(x)|$ has no minimum value.  This can be proved by contradiction.

Assume that $|f(x)|$ has a minimum value and $x_0$ is the value at which it is is smallest.  By $\forall{x}\exists{y} .|f(y)| < \frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$ there must be a $y_0$ such that $ |f(y_0)| < \frac{1}{2}|f(x_0)|$.

Since $|f(y_0)|$ is smaller then $|f(x_0)|$ it contradicts the initial assumption that $|f(x_0)|$ is the minimum value.

Comment: Yes thanks.! what about the continuity part?

Comment: Yes it is trivial then because if f is continuous then on the closed bounded interval it would attain its bounds. but we have proved that 4f$ does not have a minimum!